# Primary filegroup full on a Read-Only database in SQL and we need to change access

Tags: sql-server

I came across a strange scenario in our production server today that business wanted to add a new Login to be implemented for a read-only database. So we tried to make the Database to Read-Write mode, and it threw the below Error.

> Could not allocate space for object
> sys.sysschobjs'.'clst' in database '' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Since the filegroup is full, we tried to increase the size of the file. And for increasing the Space it said the database should be Read-Write mode to increase the size of the file

So, It is like a dead lock situation that for making DB read-write File should have some space and for increasing the size the Db should be in read-write mode. I am not sure how to get this sorted.

Comment: It's definitely an interesting scenario, I'm assuming you're not able to share a copy of the database?